# change css value on drop of droppable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable

I need to drop a span with its own css values into a div, on drop the div will take on the css value of the dropped span.
here is my code for one but I need to make it so whatever the span dropped the div will take on that value.

here is my html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.drag1, .drag2, .drag3').draggable({ containment: 'document', revert: true });
  $('#drop').droppable({ hoverClass: 'border, bgRed', tolerance: 'pointer', accept: '.drag1, .drag2, .drag3' });
});
```

```css
.drag1 {
  background-color: #900;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.drag2 {
  background-color: #036;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.drag3 {
  background-color: #060;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.border {
  border: dotted 1px #999999; 
}

.bgRed {
  background-color:#900; 
}
#drop {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">-->
<span class="drag1" title="Drag Me">Red Header</span>
<span class="drag2" title="Drag Me">Blue Header</span>
<span class="drag3" title="Drag Me">Black Header</span>

<div id="drop"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/ui.js"></script>-->
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Providing the code that your working with here will really help us out.  However, I'm afraid that I'm not exactly clear on what your question is.  Maybe you can update it to provide just a few more details, and having a question mark would also really help out here.

Answer (score 2):

If the styles are just in classes, do something using the drop event like:

```
$('#drop').droppable({ 
    hoverClass: 'border, bgRed', 
    tolerance: 'pointer', 
    accept: '.drag1, .drag2, .drag3',
    drop: function (ui, event) {
        $(this).addClass($(ui.draggable).attr('class'));
    } 
});
```

You can do whatever you want with this.  'this' is the drop element and 'ui.draggable' is the draggable element inside the drop function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a drop event you could listen for but you could probably simulate one with some logic and mouseup.  The idea being, have your div listening for a drop, check the type of span that was dropped, and apply the right class to the div based on the dropped span.

**Edit:**  I just pulled this outta my head, might not work exactly but that's part of the fun of coding.  Seeing what works and what doesn't...

```
var objToDrop = $('#div');

objToDrop.on(mouseover, function()
{
    objToDrop.on(mouseup), function() 
    {
        if(objToDrop.children().attr('class') === 'class1')
        {
            objToDrop.addClass('class1');
        }
        else if(objToDrop.children().attr('class') === 'class2')
        {
            objToDrop.addClass('class2');
        }
        else if(objToDrop.children().attr('class') === 'class3')
        {
            objToDrop.addClass('class3');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: sounds about right freethinker, but I am new to this and would appreciate a fiddle or some code please

Comment: Thanks Freethinker I have it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

your droppable has a drop event

```
$('#drop').droppable({
    accept: '.drag1, .drag2, .drag3',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
                    //$(this) is your #drop 
                    // ui.draggable is your draggable object
                    //the next line removes any previous class and adds the class of your draggable to your droppable 
        $(this).attr("class", "").addClass( $(ui.draggable).attr("class") );
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - it works perfectly and I will be able to dig into the code you gave me and change things around for other elements I nedd to change in other parts of the application, I tried to vite up but it won't let me.

Comment: This is virtually a copy of the answer I gave below.  Only difference is removing the existing classes of drop.